# Android veiwpager with fragments view flow issues

Tags: android, fragment

Im relatively new to android so im trying my hand at what i though would be an easy-ish app but I've ran into an issue to do with view/activity flow that i cant get an understanding on.

i have a fragmentActivity that uses a Viewpager to create tabs, each of those tabs is its own fragment class, thats all fine and working, but now i need to have one of the tabs display a list, when selected it takes you to another "view", my problem is how to create the first list and then how to handle tha clicking of an item in that list to take you to the new view so that the tabs stay in place and the back button doesn't exit the app.

currently ive swapped out the fragment with a list fragment that uses an arrayAdapter to build itself, this has worked as far as the list goes but i cant for the life of me figure out how to utelise its onclick() method to move on the the next screen, without as i said losing the tabs or having the back button simply exit.

so im not sure if A, the list fragment is the way to go, or B if it is how to move on to a new screen correctly

i can post code if needed but its a very general implementation of the classes mentioned so im not sure code will help

Comment: So you want a new screen to appear within the tab?

Comment: yep thats it, sounds simple and probably will be im just missing that lightbulb moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An elegant solution was finally found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15321919/1157354), it uses a wrapper fragment around my list fragment so the pager is just concerned with the wrapper, meanwhile within the wrapper i can perform fragment transactions to my hearts desire, one small note the linked code uses getChildFragmentManager() that needs to be changed to regular fragmentmanager() from support.app for the backstack stuff to work.

Answer (score 1):

The callback you want to handle a click on an item in the list is [onListItemClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29).

As far as presenting a new screen, you can use a [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) to replace your fragment with a new one, which gets a little hairy if you're doing this inside of a ViewPager. The code would look something like this:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.some_containging_view, new SomeFragment())
    .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Otherwise, you could simply launch a new Activity, which is simpler, but will mean that the tabs won't be present on the new screen unless you duplicate them there.

Comment: thanks i tried it and it produced mixed results, it mostly replaces the list fragment with a blank view, which pressing back sometimes removes bringing back the list other times it crashes the app,
this is using the android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction as suggest by the error fix using the non-support version causes the getfragmentManager() to not exist.

`
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {  
  FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  ft.replace(R.id.pager, new ReferenceTabFragment())
  .addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
`

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager() should give you the version from the support package.

Comment: thanks for the secondary reply, i just tried the supportmanager and unfortunately the app wont compile with that in place, with eclipse telling me to change it to childfragmentmanager or back to regular old fragmentmanager, neither help

Comment: on further investigation this appears to be because im using a listfragment rather then a fragmentactivity subclass.