# Replace ListFragment with Fragment inside ViewPager with Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, fragment, android-listfragment

I try to setup following navigation in my app:

Actual condition: ViewPager + Tabs to swipe between lists:

- ListFragment A
- ListFragment B

Desired condition:
ViewPager + Tabs:

- ListFragment A onListItemSelected replace ListFragment A with DetailFragment A
- ListFragment B onListItemSelected replace ListFragment B with DetailFragment B

The goal is to display the detail fragments inside the tab navigation. I can't replace the fragmentList by a detailFragment (the fragmentList has no custom layout and therefore no ID AND i don't know how to do it). 
Also, starting a new activity hides the tab bar.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would make a wrapper fragment which knows what to show - list or details. This would be completely decoupled from `ViewPager` - pager would only know it holds wrapper fragments, and these would manage their content themselves.

Implementation would be along these lines:

```java
public class WrapperFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MyListFragment list = new MyListFragment();
        list.setListAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
              // Create details fragment based on clicked item's position
              Fragment details = new Fragment();
              getChildFragmentManager()
                  .beginTransaction()
                  .replace(R.id.container, details)
                  .addToBackStack(null)
                  .commit();
            }
        });

        getChildFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, list)
            .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // There has to be a view with id `container` inside `wrapper.xml`
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.wrapper, container, false);
    }

    public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

        private OnItemClickListener listener;

        public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener l) {
            this.listener = l;
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            if(listener != null) {
              listener.onItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

`wrapper.xml`. Idea is that `WrapperFragment` has to provide a layout which contains a view with id `container` - because we're using view with this id to put child fragment - `MyListFragment` or `DetailsFragment`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

---

Another way. This should work, but you'll have to try that out (layout has `id` itself, rather than having a child with id `container`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Would the layout wrapper look like this? I get an InflateException for onCreateView.  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:name="PATH_TO_WrapperFragment"
    ... >
</fragment>

Comment: Added example for `wrapper.xml`. Let me know if you're having problems with this

Comment: What would be the fastest way to get back from the detail fragment to the list/wrapper?

Comment: `getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack()`. Notice `.addToBackStack(null)` line when displaying `DetailsFragment`. It basically says "save this transaction as a history action - one such that can be moved back from by pressing HW back button". And `popBackStack()` kinda emulates HW back button click. It may be easier to understand `backStack` management by thinking of it as similar to HTML5 History API.

Comment: Ah, and so when you do `popBackStack()`, you return to previous state - in your case that's `ListFragment`.

Comment: firstly thanks for this, its solved an issue ive been having for the past few days, secondly regarding the backstack stuff i found that changing from getChildFragmentManager() to the regular FragmentManager() from support.app enabled the back button to work without manual calls from anywhere, using the childmanager did not, not sure what side effects this will have but its all behaving how i want :D

Comment: I want same thing when clicked on a button in "Fragment A" (not listfragment). Any Idea ?

Comment: +1 Wrapper works great! But do you know why the onCreateOptionsMenu doesn't work anymore? I need it only for my listFragment

Comment: @Kevin, sorry, missed your the comment. Reason might be that `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called only on top-level fragment - wrapper. Solution could be to create menu from there - e.g. by calling  `listFragment#onCreateOptionsMenu()` manually. That's from top of the head, you'd need to try this out

Comment: @mindeh Thank you for still responding, I already found this answer and it is the same answer you gave me. It works great!